# How to fix "err connection refused" in angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api

I am building an web application with webApi and angular 7 .
The webApi part works because when I run dotnet watch run it brings my data from the database in the browser but when I connect it with angular I get err connection refused.

I checked the url. It is correct

This is my service.ts :

```
const httpOptions = {
headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};
const apiUrl = 'http://localhost:5000/api';

@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

 constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }




 private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
return (error: any): Observable<T> => {

  // TODO: send the error to remote logging infrastructure
  console.error("emptyyyyyy"); // log to console instead

  // Let the app keep running by returning an empty result.
  return of(result as T);
};
}

 getEmployees(): Observable<Employee[]> {
 return this.http.get<Employee[]>(apiUrl)
  .pipe(

    catchError(this.handleError('getSuppliers', []))
  );
  }


}
```

In the console it sayss : emptyyy and err connection refused

Comment: Is the service at http://localhost:5000 running? connection refused sometimes means the service is shutdown.

Comment: Aren't you swallowing the error? Instead of using console.error("emptyyyyyy");  Please try using console.error(error); Maybe by examining that error object, you can find out why the connection was refused.

Comment: I was trying to see if the server sends me the employee list that's why I used "empty ". And of course it was empty because the client and server did not connect .

Comment: If you used the code that you posted, how did you know that "err connection refused"?  Did you try what I posted?

Comment: From my console . It shows error connection refused and then empty . Yes . At first my code had console.error(error ) then I changed it to empty to see it my method  "get employees " throws error .

Comment: I generate my project from cmd with :dotnet  new webapi –o AspNetAngular –n AspNetAngular .   I was following a tutorial .  But it did not generate a solution just folders .  I thought that with the command : "dotnet run "  I am starting my server . Because when I did that and go in my browser to : localhost:5000/ employee . The program worked and it showed me my employee list . But apparently the server did not run when I started my angular client .